# Predict a date range of a future event

Tags: time-series, predictive-models

I have a graph like this:

[image]

The graph grows every day, and will reach 7,000 at some point in the future. My goal is to forecast a date range (e.g. October 3-7) within which this event (reaching 7,000) is likely to occur with a probability of at least 95%.

Is there a method I can use to accomplish this? I tried linear regression, but results weren't very good.

Comment: That doesn't look like a graph that's going to reach 7,000 anytime soon. It looks like it's leveling off - like an arctan or sigmoid function.

Comment: Linear regression will fail due to the high positive correlation in the values induced by the increasingness assumption.  Consider modeling the first differences instead and then using that model to predict the cumulative sum.  This has a better chance of producing more plausible confidence intervals.

Comment: Graph looks remarkably regular. Do you have any indication of what the data is representing? It seems to be some subject matter expertise would go a long way here